# Appcelerator - including different files (circular reference edition in ios)

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

In titanium appcelerator, if i have two files - A and B - what is the best way for B to reference A?

When developing for android, if i include A in B

`var xyz = require("A");`

I can then access A's methods by `xyz.someMethod();`

However, i recall that when developing for ios, the require method runs into issues where if i include it in B, and then for whatever reason include it in C which references B, i get a loop of references!

Is there some standard (ie works for ios, android, windows, whatever) method of including the files - say including them in some manner in app.js or something?

( I don't use alloy )

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you `require` you should not add `.js`.

If you require files you need to use commonjs strategy.

So if you want to access a function in `a.js` you will need to export it:

```
module.exports = {
    myFunction: myLocalFunction
}
```

you can then call this like this:

```
require('a').myFunction();
```

or

```
var a = require('a');
a.myFunction();
```

Comment: i think you're missing the heart of the question - altho noted i made a mistake in the example - but the problem is circular references in ios when i use the same style in android

Comment: if `a` needs `b` and `b` needs `a` then you've build it wrongly and probably are better off with 1 file. Dependencies are normal, circular dependencies aren't ;)